# error in database connection in cloud9.io

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, cloud9-ide

This type of questions have been asked many times before.I have tried almost every answer but can't figure out my problem.

i am having problem in mysql database connectivity in cloud9.io environment in  sails js project.

**Steps**

```
1)mysql-ctl start

2)phpmyadmin-ctl install
```

it worked and opened phpmyadmin page for me.i created db there.

```
3)mysql-ctl cli
4)mysql> \r
```

here's the problem its giving

```
connection id:1

Current database: *** NONE
```

There is no error in console while running sails lift.it gives error on executing queries.i have tried all following links related to my problem but no use.

[Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' while attempting to grant privileges. How do I grant privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484722/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-while-attempting-to-grant-privileges)

[ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989418/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-n)

[ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y)

and few more.

Comment: Using root and localhost?

Comment: nope this is the main problem..... host: process.env.IP,
      
 User:process.env.C9_USER       according to this host is myworkspace-username.c9.io and user should be username.

Comment: Where are you setting the database name?

Comment: so sorry  that was my mistake i totally ignored the settings for custom queries in waterline sails that uses database configurations too.exports.con = mysql.createConnection( {
 host :process.env.IP,
user :process.env.C9_USER,
password : '',
database : 'c9'
 });
exports.createQuery =require('./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection').createQuery;

Comment: thanx for everyone's response