# forget the temporary mysql passowrd

Tags: mysql, authentication

I cannot login to mysql since I forgot (I lost!) the temporary password I received after installing mysql. So I tried the following steps but they didn't help me:

1. I stopped mysql server
2. Then I created a file in `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/`,called `restore`, in which I wrote this line: `SET PASSWORD FOR
   root@localhost=PASSWORD('');`
3. Finally I ran this command: `sudo mysqld_safe
   --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/support-files/restore` but it stuck on `mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data`. However I checked mysql from system preference and it already started (showing "mysql is running")
4. I tried to login to mysql again with this command `mysql -u root`, but still I receive the same error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Could someone please help me fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
1. stop mysql server
2. sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
3. mysql -u root  //it should not ask password
4. use mysql; //change to mysql db
5. update user set password=PASSWORD("secure password") where user='root';
  or (depending on mysql version)
  update user set authentication_string=password('secure password') where user='root';
6. flush privileges;
7. logout from mysql (quit)

8. start mysql server (mysql -u root -p)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it worked.. but is realy strange for me.. since I did almost the same steps (the only difference was in step 2 that I used `sudo mysqld_safe --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/support-files/restore` instead of `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` ). btw, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @mOna No problem. Please accept the answer as it worked for you

Comment: yes, I tried, but I should still wait two more minutes to be able to accept :) btw, I get this error when I try to change password (i.e., in step 5): `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'`

Comment: I also tried with this command: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myNewPass'`, but I get this error: `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

Comment: its strange that you get and error and still succeed in reseting the password. Try `select * 
  from information_schema.columns 
 where table_schema = 'mysql' 
   and table_name = 'user'` and check if the password field is there. Also double check if you executed step 4

Comment: I couldn't reset the password! (I could do the step 1 to 4 without any trouble but from step 5 (reset password), I got the error). I tried the query you mentioned and it shows me the table ...

Comment: thanks to @nodejh in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692812/mysql-user-db-does-not-have-password-columns-installing-mysql-on-osx, I found there is no password field in MySQL 5.7. Instead there is `authentication_string` field, so I had to use: `update user set authentication_string=password('1111') where user='root';` and it worked for me :)

Comment: @mOna Thanks for input. I have update the answer. May be it will help someone else