# How to have "mysql" command on Mac OS?

Tags: mysql, macos

I was given a code repo which requires `mysql` in command line.

I am using Mac OS 10.11

First, I installed `MySQL Community Server` from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and install it by running the `PKG` file.

After that, I opened System Preferences to start MySQL Server.

Then, I tried to execute

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot`

and there is an error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

How could I have `mysql` in command line?

Thanks,

Comment: you already have it. you didn't provide a password, (`-p` option), so your login was denied. If you DIDN'T have the mysql client, you'd get "no such command" or whatever.

Comment: Hi, I have this message ``2016-07-05T15:36:38.772955Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: 6_fQx:dfS9H;

If you lose this password, please consult the section How to Reset the Root Password in the MySQL reference manual.``

Comment: However, when I tried with the password ``6_fQx:dfS9H``, it still reported ``Access denied``

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/406612 , restart mysql daemon, login without password, change that password ---> `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');`, Go back and ditch that info from your cnf and save. That cnf can be your best friend, a problem that gets in the way of login, or a major security risk, Restart mysql daemon

Answer (score 17):

Typically the command is:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

which will prompt you for your root password (which might be blank unless you changed it)

You can also use:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p[password]
```

but keep in mind that password will be visible onscreen as you are typing it unlike the straight `-p` option that will hide your password as you type it when prompted.

Take a look at the options for mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html

In your case, I'd try `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p` then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.  mysql will prompt you for your password - type in in and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> again.  If it's wrong mysql will let you know and then you'll have to go about resetting the mysql root password.

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/ is a reasonable set of instructions for doing that in OS X (may be out of date for your version of MySQL but the comments will help) but YMMV depending on where mysql was installed, etc...

Basically those instructions are:

1. `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`
2. `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
3. `mysql -u root`
4. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'password';`
5. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
6. `exit`
7. `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

Which

1. Stops mysql
2. Sets mysql to run without bothering with privileges
3. Opens a mysql prompt
4. Updates the root password to 'password' - you should use something else here.
5. "Cleans" passwords (some might say this is unnecessary)
6. Exits the mysql prompt
7. Starts mysql

That *should* allow you to run `mysql -u root -p` and use the new password set in #4.

Comment: Hi, could you take a look at my previous comment. I provided password but it does not work.

Comment: Hi, it's great. Could I set null password, i.e. allows to run ``mysql`` command itself without any interaction?

Comment: I think the tutorial is outdated for MySQL 5.7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692812/mysql-user-db-does-not-have-password-columns-installing-mysql-on-osx

Comment: You are correct about the tutorial being out of date but my summary should be correct.  As for running mysql without a password and as a commend without interaction...no password is never a good idea but there are options including my.conf.  What mysql command are you trying to run and from where?  That would help determine the best route.