# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) error in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have worked on the mysql database until yesterday, but today when I am trying to access mysql it gave following error.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Yes)
```

I want to get my existing databases since I have not got a backup.
Further, I have followed the step on following lnks and still haven't found the solution to my problem.

- [Resetting Permissions (MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)
- [ERROR 1045 (28000): (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989418/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-n)

Comment: I had this issue recently. Try use `sudo mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Don't you have the password for your root account?

Comment: I have password and it also gave the same erroe

Comment: Have you always used @ localhost specifically? e.g. @ 127.0.0.1 is a different user, but resolves to the same machine.

Comment: Have you tried [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw) suggested there?